# Set question, relations, equivalence classes

Tags: equivalence-relations

Let S be the set of all bit strings (a sequence of 1s and 0s) of length 3 or more.

Let R be a relation on S of all pairs (x, y) where x and y are in S if x and y have the same first two bits.

Is R is an equivalence relation? If so, how many equivalence classes are there?

Comment: Relations of the form "apply a function to both and check if the results are equal" are *always* equivalence relations, and the number of equivalence classes is the number of different results the function can have.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am still confused as to what the equivalence classes would be in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Remember that equivalence relations will induce a partition. So, ask yourself: will $S$ induce a partition on the Whole set?
How many classes I will have if there are two different ways to set zeros and ones in the position you want to.

Comment: So, (0,1) (1,0) ? So two different classes?

Comment: Whoops, (0,0) (1,1) maybe?

Comment: I would bet for the second comment you gave here.
:)

Comment: Sweet. How would i write that out? I know the answer doesn't ask for the classes, i just say there are two, but how would i write it if it asked for them?

Comment: To write it, remember that $x$ and $y$ are sequences whit length 3 or more. Then ONE equivalence class would be given by the sequences of the form $x=\left\{0,0,...\right\}$. Write that in the notation your book, teacher or webpage gave you.
Another thing to consider, there should be 4 different classes, check the form of the elements.

Comment: How come there are 4 difference classes? Isn't there only two?

Answer (score 1):

The first two bits of every string identifies uniquely the equivalence class.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you looking for is for [00][01][10][11]
I think!